Compactness of an operator on l^2
I am working on some problems from Kreyzig's Functional Analysis and got stuck on this problem:
Let $T: l^2 \rightarrow l^2$ be defined by $Tx = y = (\eta_j)$ where $x = (\xi_j) $ and $\eta_j = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_{jk}\xi_k$ where $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty |\alpha_{jk}|^2 < \infty$
We want to show that $T$ is a compact operator.
What I tried is to start by defining $T_n:l^2 \rightarrow l^2$ by $$T_nx = (\alpha_{11}\xi_1, \sum_{k=1}^2 \alpha_{2k}\xi_k,..., \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_{nk}\xi_k, 0, 0, ....)$$
The goal is to show that $||T-T_n|| \rightarrow 0$ and then we can conclude that $T$ is a compact operator, since each $T_n$ is compact.
Now
$$||(T-T_n)x||^2 = \sum_{j=n+1}^\infty |\eta_j|^2 = \sum_{j=n+1}^\infty |\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_{jk}\xi_k|^2$$
I am not sure how to proceed from here, I've tried to use the fact  $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty |\alpha_{jk}|^2 < \infty$, and isolating $||x||^2$, but not sure how to work around the double sums.

$\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty |\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_{jk}\xi_k|^2\le \sum_{j=n+1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty |\alpha_{jk}|^{2}|\sum |\xi_k|^{2}=\|x\|^{2} \sum_{j=n+1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty |\alpha_{jk}|^{2}$ and $\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty|\alpha_{jk}|^{2} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.
